# Unhandled exception in script file not found

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to Python and have just made my first app. It is a simple password manager app that stores the data structure in a .txt file. I used the Tkinter library to create my GUI and everything is working as expected. Compiling the 5 .py file into a single .exe file had no errors, but when I try to run it I get the error "Unhandeled exception in script" more specifically:
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\cohen\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI96962\base_library.zip\lock_and_key.ppm" no such file or directory.

I did use a custom image to replace the window icon of the program and it is included within the same folder as the .py file. I have tried many suggested solutions from other stackoverflow posts, but nothing seems to work. I have tried both root.iconbitmap(file path to .ico file) and I have also tried using root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, filepath to .ppm file). I checked the base_library.zip file mentioned in the path for my icon files and they were not there so I tried manually adding them there and still the same error that it can't find the file.

I have no other ideas as to why this is the case, tutorials on this step online didn't seem to do anything different.

EDIT:
As requested here is a screenshot of the error and part of the code in question.

[image: Error]

[image: Code]

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code as well as the full traceback error.

Comment: Also what program do you use to compile the exe?

Comment: I guess the issue is that you use an absolute path, and the executable only works with relative paths inside the compiled directory.

Comment: I was testing the code and writing it in Visual studio, but when I compiled it I was using the command prompt to run the pyinstaller module with the command:

pyinstaller -w -F MPM.py

Comment: I don't think the issue is with absolute paths as I used the sys.path[0] code to grab the current directory the code is in and joined it with the file used, so it shouldnt be an issue. After running the compilation command I even moved the .exe to the directory with all the images and still it didn't work.

Comment: Obviously `sys.path[0]` refers to different paths when the script is executed directly and when it is embedded in an executable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you found the solution, but the same thing happened to me:

```
root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Text Converter")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.iconbitmap("marte.ico")

myFrame = tk.Frame()
myFrame.pack()
```

I had the code like this, and each time I created the .exe I got the same error related to the icon. In the end, I tried the following:

```
root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Text Converter")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.iconbitmap(r "C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\ReallyProject\marte.ico")

myFrame = tk.Frame()
myFrame.pack()
```

Where I indicated the icon, or any type of image, I specified the full path where it was hosted. That totally fixed the problem and now any program that I create works perfectly.

Greetings!

Comment: Using absolute path will not work when the .exe is executed in other PC.

Comment: Right, this is for your own PC, to use it on another PC I don't know how to make it work.